# Integrating Ember bindings with highcharts

Tags: highcharts, ember.js

I have a javascript application written with ember.js and am looking to bind an array of day containing various stats to some charting mechanism. I have been experimenting with highcharts with no luck. I have managed to get it to update through the setInterval function, but am unsure of how to incorporate a highcharts object and an ember object to allow for bindings/computed properties.

I am just beginning with ember, and I appreciate any help/ pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a JSFiddle around which illustrates how to use Highcharts with Ember.js, see http://jsfiddle.net/Bt2xy/12/.

***EDIT***: I found the corresponding thread http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=15397, so the credits of the JSFiddle go to user **@mbloem** and **@hfrntt (Slawek Kolodziej)**.

Comment: Hello @pangratz I am a little new to ember so I am curious about this answer (and the one below)... the "chartConfig" section, is it considered a model, view, or controller?  I am using ember app kit so I want to try to keep my segments organized correctly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working version of the fiddle above, with Ember rc6 and Highcharts 2: http://jsfiddle.net/qmmvx/2/

For Highcharts 3 the options structure has changed somewhat (and broken the previous fiddle) but the idea remains the same.

Changed dependency to:

```
http://code.highcharts.com/2.2.4/highcharts.js
```